# Irrationality of $\pi$ from the spigot algorithm?

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi

The [spigot algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spigot_algorithm) for [BPP formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe_formula) gives hexadecimal digits of $\pi$ one at a time.

Is it possible to prove directly that this algorithm cannot be computed with bounded-memory? (From [R J Lipton](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2010/07/14/making-an-algorithm-an-algorithm-bbp/) It seems to take $O(\log(n))$ space as an upper bound, we need a lower bound).

That would immediately imply that it wasn't periodic and hence $\pi$ is irrational.

---

Can this proof be done? Or maybe it depends on something difficult number theoretic result about modular exponentiation? but if it could be reduced to something like that, that would be interesting too.

Comment: If we can prove that a particular algorithm is "lousy," that doesn't show there can't be a good one.

Comment: @Amzoti, why did you delete my note about O(log(n))?

Comment: Your comment got cut off. Can it be posted again?

Comment: @user58512: sorry, it was accidental and not intentional. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti, ok! I didn't want to edit it back in without your comment, in case it was against rules or something.

Comment: A bit tangential but if you do not already know it [this](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/spigot.pdf) is a delightful example of a decimal spigot algorithm for $\pi$.  (I'd call BBP a *digit extraction* algorithm instead.)

Comment: @WimC, yeah I've studied this in the past it is excellent.

Comment: I just remembered there is a BPP algorithm for $\zeta(5)$ [source](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.CA/9803067) so this question is hopeless... I think I should delete it.